# ASP .NET CORE 2.2 JWT & Claims identity Authentication for Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

I have an .net core 2.2 api which generates (on a successful login) a JWT token which contains a claims identity that passes along information such as the username, permissions and roles of the authenticated user.

In my .net core 2.2. web app I have a login mechanism which retrieves the JWT token via the user of a controller.

My question is.

How can I expand the token from within my login controller and set up my web app to include the use of the authentication mechanisms like `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, `User.IsInRole("Admin")` and controller actions like `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]`

I've been directed towards looking at the source code behind external authentication providers such as facebook/google but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you already managed to get your IdentityUser from your JWT in an authentication middleware ? Are you only looking for how to handle authorization in your controllers ?

Comment: This is what i'm after. So would you recommend introducing some authentication middleware in my startup class to create the identity user? In addition to authorizing the user on controllers, I need the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and User.IsInRole("Admin") variables setup to alter my UI depending on the user. @Skrface

Comment: hi..are you using identityserver4 or what kind of technologies?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi i'm simply trying to use cookieauthentication, claimsidentity and jwt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step is to use `cookie authentication` in `Startup.cs` :

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie();

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

In the `Configure` method, use the `UseAuthentication` method to invoke the Authentication Middleware that sets the HttpContext.User property. Call the UseAuthentication method before calling `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute` or `UseMvc`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Then in your auth controller , after getting token and decode to get the claims , you should create new `ClaimsIdentity` , add your claims and sign-in user :

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, YourName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, YourName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));

    //Add your custom claims

    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });

}
```

After that , you can use`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, `User.IsInRole("Admin")` and `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]`:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    var result = User.IsInRole("Admin");
    return View();
}
```